# Getting Value Error 'The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()' after fitting the train data

Tags: python, multilabel-classification

I keep getting the *ValueError: 'The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()'* when fitting my data that was previously split into train and test sets. How do I resolve this error?

I already checked if my data was split correctly by using *shape* property and printing the head of each *X,y* train, and test sets.

**data** - is a DataFrame that consists of one *'text'* column and six label columns.
features **X** - vectorized texts
labels   **y** - labels
**data[['text']]** - is a DataFrame of vectors
**data [ ['1'  ,'2' ,  '3' , '4' ,'5','6' ] ]** - DataFrame of labels

**Update**
The problem was indeed with my original data, as some of my vectors had really distorted shape (e.g. (19,1)). Method **flatten()** seemed to resolve the problem, as it returns a copy of the array collapsed into one dimension.

Here is how I split the data:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_test, X_train, y_test, y_train = train_test_split(data[['text']],data [ ['1'  ,'2' ,  '3' , '4' ,'5','6' ] ] , random_state=42, test_size=0.30, shuffle=True)
```

And here is the fitting part:

```
my_classifier = LabelPowerset(classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100),require_dense = [False, True])
my_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

```
print(X_test.shape)
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
```

Ouput:

```
(111699, 1)
(47872, 1)
(111699, 6)
(47872, 6)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-a59b7690b804> in <module>()
----> 1 my_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skmultilearn\problem_transform\lp.py in fit(self, X, y)
    136         """
    137         X = self._ensure_input_format(
--> 138             X, sparse_format='csr', enforce_sparse=True)
    139 
    140         self.classifier.fit(self._ensure_input_format(X),

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skmultilearn\base\base.py in _ensure_input_format(self, X, sparse_format, enforce_sparse)
     95                 return X
     96             else:
---> 97                 return matrix_creation_function_for_format(sparse_format)(X)
     98 
     99     def _ensure_output_format(self, matrix, sparse_format='csr', enforce_sparse=False):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py in __init__(self, arg1, shape, dtype, copy)
     77                         self.format)
     78             from .coo import coo_matrix
---> 79             self._set_self(self.__class__(coo_matrix(arg1, dtype=dtype)))
     80 
     81         # Read matrix dimensions given, if any

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\coo.py in __init__(self, arg1, shape, dtype, copy)
    183                     self._shape = check_shape(M.shape)
    184 
--> 185                 self.row, self.col = M.nonzero()
    186                 self.data = M[self.row, self.col]
    187                 self.has_canonical_format = True

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

```
X_train.head(5)
```

Output:

```
                                                  text
119105  [0.070629984, 0.09145695, 0.026743168, -0.0247...
131631  [0.15062076, 0.1616201, -0.24214625, -0.079838...
125326  [0.29536337, 0.148198, 0.19248627, 0.21796156,...
111256  [0.16876991, 0.035899613, -0.06388393, -0.2339...
83590   [0.14012083, 0.08112805, -0.079143375, -0.0808...
```

```
y_train.head(5)
```

Output:

```
        1   2   3   4   5   6
2783    0   0   0   0   0   0
109183  0   0   0   0   0   0
96229   0   0   0   0   0   0
128796  1   0   1   0   1   0
103592  0   0   0   0   0   0
```

How the whole vector looks like in X_train per line:

```
[ 4.0938530e-02  2.0466107e-01  2.3541172e-01 -2.2121635e-01
 -1.6204901e-01 -2.3460600e-01  9.9785912e-01 -2.0803943e-01
 -9.1773011e-02  7.8154532e-03 -4.5910537e-02  1.6967587e-01
 -4.1978297e+00 -2.0136276e-01  1.3398567e-03  6.2967308e-02
  2.1797931e-01 -3.2942373e-01 -1.3567382e-01 -3.2139298e-01
 -1.1644501e-01  3.7298296e-02 -3.3780817e-02 -1.4053656e-01
 -2.2851831e-01]
```

```
y_train.all()
```

Output:

```
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
dtype: bool
```

```
y_train.any()
```

Output:

```
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is not clear if `data` is a dataframe or `data[['text']]` is a dataframe. Can you please edit your question and add an example of the data? For example, you can do `data[['text']].head()`.

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă hope it is more clear like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is originating from the format of your data. It looks like your `X_train` only has two columns: the ID column and a `text` column, which *is an array*. You will want to split the text column to resemble the format of `y_train`.

To understand the error message, consider this:

```py
bool(5)
# True
bool(0)
# False
```

Now if you try to convert an array (your data) to bool, how is it going to evaluate?

```py
>>> a = np.array([3, 12, 5, 0, 2, 0])
>>> a.any()
True
>>> a.all()
False
>>> bool(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

As the error tells  you, it is ambiguous. Use `a.any()` to check if any of the elements are `True` and `a.all()` to check whether all elements are true.

Now back to the original problem: The error is occuring in a pre-build `sklearn` function, which is a hint, that the data you put into it is wrongly formatted (doesn't match some of the prerequisites of the function). Errors on the module side of `sklearn` should be rare.

**EDIT:** I'm actually quite sure the data format is the problem. If you follow the stack-trace, the error occurs in `_ensure_input_format()`, while checking for non-zero values `self.row, self.col = M.nonzero()`.

**EDIT 2:** Adjusted solution for supplied data.

Comment: I'm now also sure that the problem is in my data. However, I have no idea what is wrong with it.  `X_train.head(5)` produces  table where rows look like this `119105 [0.070629984, 0.09145695, 0.026743168, -0.0247...
`

Comment: @zoandr please add that output in your question, as block-code (indent everything 4 spaces). I'm not sure if `text` and `119105` are part of the rows or just the name of the dataframe.

Comment: Added output to the question. `119105` is id, it has nothing to do with my original dataset.

Comment: Do you think the problem is in the `X_train` or `y_train`?

Comment: The mistake is that your `X_train` only has two columns: the `ID` column and a `text` column, which is an array. You will want to split the `text` column to resemble the format of `y_train`.